# sort observablecollection which is bound to ItemSource

Tags: wpf, sorting, observablecollection, itemscontrol

I am using **ItemsControl** in my application and its **ItemSource** is an observable collection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ASPTrunks}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ASPTrunkTemplate}"
                      Style="{StaticResource ItemControlStyle}">
```

**ASPTrunks** has a property named **SpTypeName**. I want controls in my ItemsControl to be sorted in alphabetical order of **SpTypeName**. what is the better way to do it. Do I need to use CollectionViewSource or is it good to sort collection programatically? if I need to use CollectionViewSource I will use it as per this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151215180945/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/387#.V7N5c0196is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either approach is fine, it will depend on if the sorting is view specific and you wish to reuse the collection in various views, then it makes sense to do the sorting in the view.

Comment: Hi, I just tried to sort ASPTrunks collection using LINQ OrderBy query. but its not working. then how can do this sorting in C#. is there any other option than LINQ orderby or sort?

Comment: Is the followinf approach is better performancewise? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5909dbcc-9a9f-4260-bc36-de4aa9bbd383/

Comment: Can you add the code for your sorting that isn't working? Yes, one approach would be to add a CollectionView to your view model, and then bind to that from your view. See http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html for a useful tutorial. Also, don't forget that WPF creates a default collection view for every collection used as a binding source anyway, so there is no real difference in performance. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections for more details.